# Do we have to invoke default constructor from class Object in its' subclass

Tags: java, object, constructor

Is there any difference if I do or do not invoke `Object`'s default constructor in the class:

```
public class BankCustomer {
    private Person owner;

    public BankCustomer(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class BankCustomer {
    private Person owner;

    public BankCustomer(Person owner) {
        super();
        this.owner = owner;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not in this case. If you use non-default constructors that take some arguments instead, this can become a different story.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where/how did you get this thought? I would understand if you wondered about this for classes that explicitly descended from a superclass, but `Object`...

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester The case you talk about is obvious. I never thought about that case I mentioned in OP.

Comment: Well personally I think it's the other way around so that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.  If you do not call a superclass constructor explicitly, then Java will insert an implicit call to the default superclass constructor as the first statement in your constructor.

The [JLS, Section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) states:

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

In your case it's completely unnecessary.  Although there is no harm in leaving `super();` there, I would remove it.

Comment: Is leaving it (`super();`) is in bad taste?

Comment: @Yoda I can't think of any reason to leave it there, especially when you're just inheriting from `Object`.

Comment: @Yoda you can leave it for classes that you explicitly let inherit a superclass, to indicate (to fellow developers) that no arguments need to be passed to the superclass's constructor.